# Eclipse PreferencePage "Apply" and "OK" greyed-out

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a newcomer to Eclipse `PreferencePages` and am currently creating a new `FieldEditorPreferencePage` for my project. However, having `FileFieldEditors()` or `DirectoryFieldEditors()` greys-out the "Apply" and "OK" buttons in my custom preference page. On the other hand, the other `FieldEditors` (Boolean- and Combo-) do not disable the "Apply" and "OK" buttons.

Furthermore, changing everything to Xtext's LanguageRootPreferencePage seems to work as well (though I'd prefer not to use it as I want the custom preference page to show up in it's own tab).

For example:

```
//Simplified example of code
public class XPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage, IWorkbenchPropertyPage {
   public XPreferencePage() {
      super(FieldEditorPreferencePage.GRID);
      setDescription("something");
   }

   protected void initialize() {
      super.initalize();
      //IPropertyChangeListeners go here
   }

   protected void createFieldEditors() {
      //"Apply" and "OK" works here
      g = new BooleanFieldEditor(SConstants.GENERATOR, "Generate Bindings", getFieldEditorParent());
      addField(g);

      //"Apply" and "OK" is greyed-out starting here
      gp = new FileFieldEditor(SConstants.GENERATOR_PATH, "Generator Path:", false, 0, getFieldEditorParent());
      gp.setEmptyStringAllowed(true);
      addField(gp);
      ...
   }
...
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this? I followed the tutorial from Eclipse [Article-Field-Editors](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Field-Editors/field_editors.html) but it doesn't seem to work for me. Reading online says it can be due to negative `IntegerField` (which I don't have) or that I'm trying to change the default settings (which I don't have either).

I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0.

**UPDATE:** The code above (partially) worked for `FileFieldEditors`. However, for some reason I need to click `FileFieldEditor` field and check and uncheck the checkbox directly above the `FileFieldEditor` for each `FileFieldEditor` in the preference page before the "Apply" and "OK" buttons are available again.

Furthermore, I have also implemented a `IPropertyChangeListener` which deactivates certain fields when certain checkboxes are unchecked which means this "check and uncheck" workaround would not work for me. I have also tried setting the default focus to one of my checkboxes but that didn't work

Comment: Is there a message displayed at the top of the page?

Comment: Nope there are no messages though I get a warning in the console of my run configuration saying "Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set." but I'm guessing this does not effect the "Apply" and "OK" buttons. However, I just found out that when I go into my PreferencePage and try to go to a different one, it says "Could not accept changes - The currently displayed page contains invalid values" which is strange since it does not contain any. I also get the same error when I input something into the filefieldeditor.

Comment: I mean a message at the top of the preference page when the buttons are greyed out. FileFieldEditor appears to always show a message.

Comment: Page contains invalid values often means an exception has occured. Look in the .log file

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see any messages at the top of the preference page. The "Apply" and "OK" buttons are already greyed-out when I first open the preference page. The only thing I see above my fieldeditors is my page description and the name of the tab.

Comment: Another strange thing I noticed is that if I press "Restore Defaults", the "Apply" and "OK" buttons are enabled again. (Sorry for the multiple comments, character limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileFieldEditor(String name, String labelText, Composite parent)` defalult validates the path when the text widget loose the focus that is what you are giving invalid as default value.
For e.g. if you give `C:\\User\\XXX` then this path should physically exist then and only it will not grey out ok and apply button.

You can also use below constructor by setting your validation stratergy.

```
FileFieldEditor(String name, String labelText,boolean enforceAbsolute, int validationStrategy, Composite parent)
```

value of `validationStrategy`

- 1 for the editor performs validation only when the text widget
  loses focus.
- 0 for the editor performs validation after every key
  stroke.

Comment: That (partially) worked for FileFieldEditors. However, for some reason, I need to check and uncheck the BooleanFieldEditor directly above the FileFieldEditor before the "Apply" and "OK" are available again. Furthermore, if I check and uncheck another checkbox and then check and uncheck the checkbox directly above the FileFieldEditor, "Apply" and "OK" stays greyed-out. This means the "Apply" and "OK" buttons stays greyed-out no matter what I click when I have multiple FileFieldEditors.

Comment: Reason behind "Apply" and "OK" stays greyed-out is validation.
That means you are having wrong values in your any of field editor. See implementation of FieldEditor class.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. At first, I thought that wrong values could not have been the problem has I did not have any but I now added the default value "" for my FileFieldEditors and DirectoryFieldEditors and the "Apply" and "OK" are working now.